# Stack OverFlow with Recursion

Tags: c++

There is a stack overflow from my code I do not really know what is causing it. Parent is a fixed array like 14.

```
protected:
int* parent = new int[14];
int size = 14;

int Tree::level(int i) {
  int count = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if (parent[i] == -1) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count = level(i) + 1; //this is causing the stack Overlow
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: if `parent[i]` is `unsigned`, this could be bad.  Consider putting a breakpoint on the `count = 1` condition to be sure.  It'd be nice to know `size` too... Please add a runable example and make sure you have no warnings when compiling.

Comment: `14` is not an array, so what did you mean? Anyway, why do you use recursion there at all?

Comment: Please post the definition and data of the parent array. Also, I assume you mean `level(i+1)`?

Comment: Can you please give us more info on the error? Have you tried debugging to see what was the state of your program when it crashed? Can we see the `parent` array? The value of `size`? Afaik, instantiating 2 `int`s will overflow your stack with too much recursion.

Comment: @J.R. `i` never change, so it should be calling the same thing forever

Comment: Seems he meant `level(j) +1`...

Comment: parent is an Array of ints i.e. int* parent = new int[14] and the size is also 14;

Comment: @Amadeus My bad. Some info on the intent of the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The recursive call in the following call is bound to cause an infinite recursion since `i` is not changed in the function.

```
count = level(i) + 1;
```

I am guessing that you meant to use `j` or `parent[i]` instead of `i` in that call. It's hard to tell what is the right value to use in the recursive call without more context.

Comment: Did not find `j`, did you mean `parent[i]`?

Comment: @Deduplicator, `j` is the loop variable. You bring another valid point though. It could be `parent[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of condition `parent[i] == -1` false, function "level" becomes infinite recursive and hence stack overflow.